# PyQt - cannot add buttons to tree children

Tags: python, button, pyqt, tree

I create a tree-view that should look like:

```
parent1
    path branch [button]
    path branch [button]
    ...
```

I create the tree like this

```
def create_tree(self,containerWidget):
  self.repo_tree = QTreeView(self)
  self.repo_tree.setGeometry(10, 10, 580, 380)

  self.repo_tree_model = QStandardItemModel()
  self.repo_tree.setModel(self.repo_tree_model)

  containerWidget.addWidget(self.repo_tree)
```

I add a parent and the children like this

```
def add_tree_repo(self,repo_url, repo_name, branch, repo_path,config,worktrees):
  root_item = QStandardItem(repo_name)
  self.repo_tree_model.appendRow(root_item)

  for worktree in worktrees:
     child1 = QStandardItem(worktree["path"])
     child2 = QStandardItem("[" + worktree["branch"] + "]")
     root_item.appendRow([child1,child2])

     button = QToolButton()
     button.setMaximumSize(button.sizeHint())
     self.repo_tree.setIndexWidget(child2.index(), button)

  self.repo_tree.update()
  self.repo_tree.expandAll()
```

only the path displays:

```
parent1
    path
    path
    ...
```

what am I missing ? any help appreciated

Comment: You need to set the column count of the model, having multiple columns in child items alone is not sufficient. Just do `self.repo_tree_model.setColumnCount(2)`.

Answer (score 0):

apparently this solves it

```
self.repo_tree_model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3"])
```